# Creating a record using has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have the following models:

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :department_job_titles
  has_many :job_titles, through: :department_job_titles
end

class JobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
end

class DepartmentJobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :job_title
  validates :department_id, uniqueness: { scope: :job_title_id }
end
```

This is erring w `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column department_job_titles.title does not exist
LINE 1: ... "department_job_titles"."department_id" = $1 AND "departmen...`

```
Department.first.department_job_titles.find_or_create_by(title: title)
```

DepartmentJobTitle has the following fields: `id, department_id, job_title_id`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to add a new `JobTitle`, add a new `DepartmentJobTitle` for an existing `JobTitle`, or add both?

Comment: I already have the department created... I was . trying to represent that with `Department.first`... I'm now trying to assign a JobTitle to the department, and I need to either create the JobTitle or find and assign it via the DepartmentJobTitle model....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
job_title = JobTitle.find_or_create_by(title: title)
Department.first.job_titles << job_title unless job_title.in? Department.first.job_titles
```

Or that second line could be:

```
Department.first.job_titles = (Department.first.job_titles + [job_title]).uniq
```

Also:

```
class JobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :department_job_titles
  has_many :departments, through: :department_job_titles
end
```

... and ...

```
class DepartmentJobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :job_title
  validates :department, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :job_title }
  validates :job_title, presence: true
end
```

... and think about what behaviour you want if someone destroys a `JobTitle` or `Department` -- either you want the DepartmentJobTitle destroyed also, or you want the `destroy` to be prevented, I expect.

Comment: Thanks, but do I have the model associations setup correctly?

Comment: Ah good point. I updated. I would also validate based on the association names, not the ids: `validates :department, uniqueness: { scope: :job_title }`, and add `inverse:` options on the `has_many`.

Comment: Not sure I'm following the `inverse` suggestion... Where would I add that and why?

Comment: Have a look at the RailsGuides on the `inverse:` -- it's added to an association to allow the inverse association to re-use the original instance.

Comment: thanks, not sure I totally follow how to add inverse yet but that doesn't seem like something I need to solve now?

Comment: Not right now, but make a note to look into it. And to beware of any code that uses references an `_id` instead of an object.